# In IE10 animation transition is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-10

I am testing my site and in Internet Explorer when I scroll down animations appear but they are not working correctly, to be specific they are not smooth animations like in Chrome, transitions are buggy.

I can't find a solution to this problem, did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: You will have to provide more details about what you did and tried, so people can help you

Comment: I do not know what to do, that's why i'm asking. It is exactly as i described it, in all other browsers animations are working like they should. When i scroll down animations appear in different ways, but in IE10 they are just not appearing as smooth as they should. Animation does happen but it is  like buggy, appearing  one part at the time, like when when you play a game and it gets stuck and half a second later it unfreezes but commands that you clicked when it froze take effect. It's hard to explain and site is not on server at this moment so i can't show you.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example so others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: also have issues with ie10, ie11 is ok.